# Unable to host web service in IIS

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, wcf-hosting

I've been working on a webservice, and testing it by viewing it in a browser directly from VS2012, but now I need to host it in IIS, and for some reason, it simply will not work.

I've tried publishing it as a new web application under my local IIS. It shows up as it should, but when I switch to Content View in IIS, right-click the `MyService.svc` file, and choose "browse", all I get is a new web-browser window saying the site was not found.

To check if the problem was relating to something in my service, or was general, I tried creating a new test-service from a VS project template (a new **WCF Service Application**), which i compiled, ran in my browser nicely, then tried to publish to IIS, with the same result.

A little extra info:

- I'm working on 64-bit windows 8
- Both projects are in .Net 4.0
- My configuration has Platform Target set to Any CPU
- In IIS, the services use the **DefaultAppPool** with default settings

I've been able to publish a website in IIS recently, and it works fine - I really thought the process was supposed to be just about the same for a service, but apparently I'm missing something.

***Update***: A little extra info in response to comments below:

- I'm currently trying to view the service locally
- There is no `.asmx` file, only a `.svc` file, a `web.config`, and a `bin/` folder in the folder where the service is published.
- I do have a site running under the same IIS website ("Default Web Site"), and that works fine.

Any tips as to what I can try in order to resolve this will be greatly appreciated....

Comment: Are you viewing `MyService.svc` locally on the IIS server?

Comment: @Kjartan....you want to browse the MyService.asmx file

Comment: Check if the site (e.g. Default Web Site) under which you have put your service is running. Also, try creating a very simple HTML page, putting it along with .svc file and try browsing to it.

Comment: Could you show your `Web.config` file? It could be a mistake in the `system.serviceModel` section.

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11460142/cannot-serve-wcf-services-in-iis-on-windows-8

Comment: Updated the question in response to the comments here.

Comment: @mattyB Thanks, that did in fact solve my problem. I just needed to enable HTTP Activation for .Net Framework Advanced Services.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the record, this was what solved the problem for me:

[image: enable HTTP Activation]