# WCF service hosting in IIS 7.5 - The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, iis-7.5

Whenever I publish WCF service to IIS. It is almost I have become habituated to get this error:

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found The page you are requesting cannot be
>   served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a
>   script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME
>   map.

The practice I have maintained: is to change application pool for the website to `classic mode`.
But this time I am out of luck.

- Q.1. Can you please help?
- Q.2. As the error suggests: Should I configure .svc MIME map some
  where in IIS?
- Q.3. For WCF to operate in integrated pipeline mode, Is there any specific
  configuration required?

Comment: **See Also**: [WCF on IIS8; \*.svc handler mapping doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11116134/1366033)

Comment: This should be open because this is the ACTUAL error... I never found the original page, just this one.  Good job, person who asked this question.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Try enabling `HTTP Activation`

Go to Control Panel > Windows Features > .NET Framework 4.5 Advanced Services > WCF Services > HTTP Activation(*tick this*)

[image: Add Windows Features]

Comment: I can't believe, you solved it in a fraction of second! Share your secret, where did you learn WCF?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. If you really believe your answer can help others, don't forget to upvote the question :-)

Comment: As WCF gets smaller in the rearview mirror fundamental nuggets like this become more valuable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For me I simply needed to add the specific mimetype to the IIS website I was running

Per [Adding Static Content MIME Mappings `<mimeMap>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/staticcontent/mimemap):

> 1. Open Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager
> 2. In the Connections pane, go to the site, application, or directory for which you want to add a MIME type.
> 3. In the Home pane, double-click MIME Types.
>    [image: IIS > Mime Types]
> 4. In the MIME Types pane, click Add... in the Actions pane.
>    [image: Add MIME Type]
> 5. In the Add MIME Type dialog box, add the file name extension and MIME type, and then click OK.
>    [image: Add MIME Type]

Comment: Thanks, I also did **second step** from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15217209/2218697) post.