# i am running wcf service not working on iis

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, rest, iis

I am working on wcf first time so created just sinple wcf ,problem is when i run service from visual studio its working fine but when i deploy it on iis it giving HTTTP 500 Error

my web config file is as below

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="WcfService2.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="servicebehavior">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="WcfService2.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="servicebehavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="web">
          <webHttp/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https"/>
    </protocolMapping>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="false" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <!--
        To browse web app root directory during debugging, set the value below to true.
        Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing web app folder information.
      -->
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and svc file is as below

```
namespace WcfService2
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "Service1" in code, svc and config file together.
    // NOTE: In order to launch WCF Test Client for testing this service, please select Service1.svc or Service1.svc.cs at the Solution Explorer and start debugging.
    public class Service1 : IService1
    {
        public string JSONData(string id)
        {
            return "you requested prduct" + id ;
        }

        public void DoWork()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

and interface is as below

```
namespace WcfService2
{
    // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the interface name "IService1" in both code and config file together.
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate = "/json/{id}")]
        string JSONData(string id);

        void DoWork();
    }
}
```

Comment: Most time IIS will show error details

Comment: What version of IIS are you running? and post the error.

Comment: Config Error    This configuration section cannot be used at this path. This happens when the section is locked at a parent level. Locking is either by default (overrideModeDefault="Deny"), or set explicitly by a location tag with overrideMode="Deny" or the legacy allowOverride="false".
Config File    \\?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\web.config

Comment: running on windows 8 machine

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9794985/iis-this-configuration-section-cannot-be-used-at-this-path-configuration-lock

Comment: Do you have https enabled in IIS ?

Comment: @Uriil   now i am getting 400.13 error

Comment: The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11460220/2211593

my iis server was not having feature of HTTP activation enabled so after lot of googling i found this solution. very useful for me i spent almost half of day to find the solution of this small issue