# WCF service page is downloading when deployed on server

Tags: wcf

i have deployed a WCF service on server but when i am calling the service, the service page gets downloaded.

I have also deployed the same service on my local IIS. On my local system its working fine.

Comment: Sounds like a problem with mime-types. I'm no expert at all with WCF, but I remember having a similar problem.

Comment: Here, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15217209/2024434

Comment: Thanks, I will try it today. AT the first i was getting other error but when i have added Mime type then error has gone but when calling, the page is downloading

Comment: Ok, maybe you have the wrong mime-type then.