# HTTP Error 404.3 - Not found - The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration

Tags: wcf, iis, iis-7

HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

The page you are requesting cannot be served because of the extension configuration. If the page is a script, add a handler. If the file should be downloaded, add a MIME map.

what could be the reason of this error for the WCF service hosted on IIS 7.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found" while browsing wcf service on Windows Server 2008(64bit)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274525/http-error-404-3-not-found-while-browsing-wcf-service-on-windows-server-2008)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3274525/http-error-404-3-not-found-while-browsing-wcf-service-on-windows-server-2008/25262844#25262844)

Please make sure you've activated WCF components from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732012.aspx).

Or alternate and easy way is, go to control panel -> Turn Windows feature on or off -> and make sure you've all the options ticked as mentioned in below screenshot.

[image]

Run from cmd:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir
```

Comment: It worked for me installing from "Turn Windows feature on or off" and without running aspnet_regiis.exe -ir. Note that I got this issue after a Windows 10 update (everything worked before). IIS have to be installed before .NET.

Answer (score 18):

All you need to do is enable HTTP Activation and any other features that are required for HTTP activation.

For Windows Server 2012,Go to server manager, on the dashboard --> click on Add roles and features. In the Wizard window that opens choose the appropriate server and go on clicking next until you are on the features selection page.

Depending on the version of .NET framework in use on your server you have to check HTTP Activation under WCF Services and proceed to install it. This should resolve your issue.

[image: Enable HTTP Activation]

Comment: thank you for including Win server 2012 as it's a different process than  8 or 10

Comment: Enablign "HTTP Activation" option worked for me on Win 10. Thanks SanthoshM

Comment: What is **TCP Activation**? Why would not having **TCP Activation** enabled cause IIS to be unable to server `.aspx` files? Why is **TCP Activation** disabled by default if it is critical to using IIS as a web-server? Under what circumstances would i not want to use **TCP Activation**? How does **TCP Activation** relate to `.aspx`?

Answer (score 0):

Run Visual Studio 2008 Command Prompt as “Administrator”.
Navigate to C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation.
Run this command servicemodelreg –i

Thanks for the blog from Rahul.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rjohri/archive/2009/06/29/the-page-you-are-requesting-cannot-be-served-because-of-the-extension-configuration.aspx